# Fancybox 2 - SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm trying to make a custom dialog box using the fancybox plugin v2

Unfortunately, when I try to manage the display of the button with the fancybox tpl parameter I get this error:
**SyntaxError: missing : after property id** --> if(cbtn == 'default')

```
var modalMessage = function (dialmsg, action, cbtn)
{
    // Set defaults if not defined
    if (typeof dialmsg === 'undefined' || dialmsg === null)
    {
        dialmsg = 'Default message';
    }
    if (typeof action === 'undefined' || action === null)
    {
        action = 'default';
    }
    if (typeof cbtn === 'undefined' || cbtn === null)
    {
        cbtn = 'default';
    }
    // Create fancybox dialog
    $.fancybox({
        'minHeight'         : 40,
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'autoSize'          : true,
        'autoHeight'        : true,
        'autoWidth'         : true,
        'fitToView'         : true,
        'closeBtn'          : false,
        'modal'             : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'inline',
        'href'              : '#modal-msg',
        'padding'           : 10,
        tpl:
        {
            if(cbtn == 'default')
            {
                closeBtn: '<div id="myCloseID">Close</div>';
            }
        },
        beforeShow: function()
        {
            $('#modal-msg').html(dialmsg);
        },
        afterClose : function()
        {
            if(action == 'reload')
            {
                parent.location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

$('#dialog').on('click', function ()
{
    modalMessage('This is a test message', 'reload');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">Click me</div>
<div id="modal-msg"></div>
```

I tried in this way

```
 tpl: function()
        {
            if(cbtn == 'default')
            {
                closeBtn: '<div id="myCloseID">Close</div>';
            }
        }
```

The error disappears but it does not appear the dialog box but only the background overlay.

How could I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation you can use a self execution function which returns the tpl object:

```
...
tpl: (function() {
    var tpls = {};

    if(cbtn == 'default') {
        tpls.closeBtn = '<div id="myCloseID">Close</div>';
    }

    return tpls;
} ())
...
```